# Laravel DI: call controller method without passing injected variable, is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel

```
class SomeController extends Controller {

  public function doALot(Request $request) {

    $this -> doOne($someOtherVariable);
    // Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\SomeController::doOne() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

    $this -> doOne($request, $someOtherVariable);
    // Bad practice?
    ...
  }

  public function doOne(Request $request, $someOtherVariable) {}
  ...    
}
```

So how do one call `doOne()` from `doALot()` without passing injected resource, yet having `Request` in `doOne()`? It feels like bad practice to pass `$request` all over the place.

**Solution tl;dr not possible, but there are other ways – read short answer from Alexey Mezenin**

Long version (probably not the best yet suffice).

```
$ php artisan make:provider SomeServiceProvider
```

Then in created provider edit `register()` call to something along the lines:

```
public
function register() {
    $this -> app -> bind('App\Services\SomeService', function ($app) {
        return new SomeService();
    });
}
```

Then proceed to create service class which will have injected resource as attribute.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class SomeService {
    private $request;

    /**
     * SomeService constructor.
     */
    public
    function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this -> request = $request;
    }

    public function doOne($someOtherVariable) {}
}
```

Then move your methods from controller to service and inject service into controller instead.

Tradeoffs: (-) two useless files to perform basic functionality, (+) detaches logic implementation from controller, (~) probably cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to call controller actions manually. The business [logic should be in the service class](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#business-logic-should-be-in-service-class). You can see an example of that in my Laravel best practices repo. If you don't want to pass `$request` object every time, you can inject `Request` class in service class' or controller constructor.

Another way to use `Request` data is to use `request()` helper:

```
request('key')
request()->has('key')
```

Or `Request` facade:

```
Request::has('key')
```

Or you can manually inject it inside the method:

```
$request = app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
```

Comment: Just to be clear – the problem here is unavailability of `$request` in `doOne()`.